# JSSOR slider - Right Arrow doesn't appear

Tags: slider, jssor, arrows

I am using the "**Nearby Image Partial Visible**" slider in my jspx page. The slider works fine except for one issue. The right arrow for navigation does not appear. ALthough my source code is correct, when I run the page the structure is changed. By looking at the HTML DOM of the page, I figured that is because the  of the right arrow is nested inside  element of the left arrow.

My source code for the arrows is the following-

```
    <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora13l" style="top: 123px; left: 30px;">
    </span>
    <!-- Arrow Right -->
    <span u="arrowright" class="jssora13r" style="top: 123px; right: 30px;">
    </span>
    <!--#endregion Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
```

But in the browser the HTML is as follows:

```
<span u="arrowleft" class="jssora13l" style="top: 123px; left: 30px;">
            <!-- Arrow Right -->

          <span u="arrowright" class="jssora13r" style="top: 123px; right: 30px;">
          </span>
</span>
```

I cant figure out the issue. Please help.

Comment: Does it happen on jssor.com? What's your device/browser version? Please leave an url of your page.

Comment: It does not happen on jssor.com.
I am using Firefox version 31.4.0 and Google Chrome Version 43.0.2357.81 m.. Currently I have not hosted my page on any server.
Is it necessary for me to use HTML5 Doctype?
the jspx page is currently using HTML4 DOCTYPE

Comment: I need to open a page to address the problem.